# How do you run a short multiplayer Conspiracy draft tournament?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-drafting, tournament, mtg-multiplayer

There is a new set in Magic the Gathering coming out, called Conspiracy. Conspiracy is a set specifically designed for drafting, and notably, multiplayer games.

My question revolves around how to fairly run a tournament for a *multiplayer draft*.

Normally my group of 6-8 will play 3-4 rounds of swiss pairings, where 3 points are awarded for a win, 1 for a tie, and 0 for a loss. Tie breaks are based off of things such as games won percentage and opponents win percentage (we use [mtgarena.appspot.com](http://mtgarena.appspot.com/) for handling this part). Our drafts normally take around 4 hours (an evening after work). We have a lot of experience with this and are very comfortable with it.

Now, I do not have a lot of experience playing multiplayer magic, but in my experience games tend to take a lot longer.

- Is there a "standard" way of running a multiplayer tournament?
- How do you determine who plays who in a round?
- Is it feasible to run a "fair" multiplayer tournament in 4-5 hours?

Comment: I'm assuming they'll have some instructions for FNM organizers around release time.

Comment: @AlexP I'm pretty certain that Conspiracy will _not_ be available as an FNM format precisely because of the issues around making suitable multiplayer tournaments; WotC might have suggestions as to how stores can run Conspiracy drafts on their own, but FNM tends to be a 'grinder format' and I wouldn't expect them to turn it over to the politics of multiplayer.

Answer (score 5):

Since multiplayer games tend to run longer than single-player matches, it's hard to do as many rounds as you would for e.g. a standard pod of 8.  The scheme we've come up with at my LGS is to run two rounds with swiss pairing and per-game prize support:

1. Do the draft itself.  For convenience, I'm going to presume a perfect 8-person pod here.
2. Break into two 4-person groups (WotC suggests randomly, but even/odd would also work well here)
3. Each group plays a single four-person game; award prize support to the top two finishers in each group.  (My LGS is going to do 3 packs for first and 1 for second here, but if you want your draft to perfectly utilize a 36-pack box, then you can go 2/1.)
4. 'Swiss' the players for a second round: the top two players from each of the two round-1 games form a new four-person group, and the bottom two players from the round-1 games also form a new four-person group.
5. Play out the second round of games, with the same prize support as the first: 2 or 3 packs to the first-place finisher in each group, and 1 pack to the second-place finisher.

This way, (a) everyone gets to play a couple of games with their deck (and don't be surprised if folks play again on their own after the draft); (b) everyone but the bottom couple of finishers gets *some* measure of prize support (which IMHO is important for a political and 'casual' environment like Conspiracy); and (c) players are incentivized to win their games and not just play for top-2.

Answer (score 2):

Last time we held a multiplayer tournament at my local store, we followed a procedure similar to the one below. It worked well, and was significantly *shorter* than the typical "Swiss draft followed by top 4/8/16 single elimination".

1. Players are randomly placed into pods of 8-9
2. Players draft with their pods
3. After drafting, each pod is randomly split into groups of 4-5
4. Players play with their group

In [this article](http://www.wizards.com/magic/magazine/article.aspx?x=mtg/daily/feature/conspiracymechanics) on Conspiracy mechanics, Wizards of the Coast backs up the procedure I described above, but they also don't specify how to award prizing. Here is the relevant excerpt from the article:

> A Conspiracy draft works well with eight players, breaking into two
>   four-player games after the draft. However, it's fun for any number of
>   players. We recommend you have no more than eight players in any draft
>   and no more than five players in any game, but experiment to see what
>   works best for your group.

Our store owner awarded a pack per player that you specifically knocked out. This changed the politics of the game drastically, and although I wouldn't encourage it, it *did* speed up the games significantly. Instead, I suggest awarding prizes according to the order in which players were knocked out. It's possible that the winner didn't knock *anyone* out, but he still won and should be rewarded accordingly (in my opinion).

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding, but I do not see how this is a tournament. It sounds like a draft followed by a single round. How would pairings for follow up rounds work?

Comment: @bengoesboom I was merely pointing out how Wizards of the Coast (an official source) suggested the draft be run, and how my local game store (a personal experience) ran it. I inserted my own feelings and suggestions where I thought they were appropriate. Since you asked, I went ahead and added a paragraph (containing only my opinions), explaining why I personally would not run multiple rounds. The truth is, if the store finds a way to do it that makes the players happy, that's really all that matters. And when the official instructions come out, none of this will matter.

Comment: @bengoesboom Now that Conspiracy has been released, I can confirm that the four steps listed in my answer are *exactly* how the drafts were intended to be run. In fact, you can even call the [Wizards game support hotline](http://company.wizards.com/contact-us) and ask them yourself.